# What ressources of my computer does Holographic Remoting Player utilize most?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Hello I am working on a project where I want to show high polygon 3D-objects. I figured out the Holographic Remoting Player is the easiest and fastest way to get it running. My question is: Does Holographic Remoting need a powerful CPU or GPU? On the official site of Microsoft it says it needs at least a GTX 970, but it still doesn't run smoothely. What CPU is the minimum requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. It turns out the problem lies with the Unity Engine, which is really not ressource efficient. When the app gets built in Visual Studio it runs nearly without flaws. Unity requires a very powerful CPU. https://www.pugetsystems.com/recommended/Recommended-Systems-for-Unity-188/Hardware-Recommendations

Answer (score 0):

In addition to computer hardware requirements, you also need to pay attention to your wireless network environment, please ensure the Bit rate and stability of your wireless network. Check out what Microsoft suggested here: [PC System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holographic-remoting-player#pc-system-requirements).

If you cannot confirm the reason for the holographic stuttering, you can follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holographic-remoting-player#diagnostics) to enable Diagnostics, the number of FPS and Latency will show you(in HoloLens1), the former number dependent on your hardware device, and the latter number is largely dependent on your Wi-Fi network.